# knockoutjs create new object when item checked

Tags: knockout.js

Following this example from the knockout documentation:

```
<!-- ko foreach: items -->
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.chosenItems" />
    <span data-bind="text: itemName"></span>
<!-- /ko -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        items: ko.observableArray([
            { itemName: 'Choice 1' },
            { itemName: 'Choice 2' }
        ]),
        chosenItems: ko.observableArray()
    };
</script>
```

I have created a list of objects that when checked using a checkbox, get added to a new list (the chosenItems).

What I would like to do is have my chosen items list consist of the object with some extra properties. For example, if I select 'Choice 1' from above, I'd like my chosen items to looks like:

```
[ { itemName: 'Choice 1', itemTitle : "", somethingElse : "" }]);
```

I've managed to do this by creating another observableArray and subscribing to the chosenItems, then when the chosenItems change, I recreate the second array manually but I'd like to know if there is a more succinct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
        { itemName: 'Choice 1' },
        { itemName: 'Choice 2' }
    ]),
    chosenItems: ko.observableArray(),

};
viewModel.chosenItems.subscribe(function(chkVals){                  
    if(chkVals && chkVals.length > 0){
        var obj = chkVals[chkVals.length-1];
        if(!obj.itemTitle || !obj.itemTitle)
        {                   
            obj.itemTitle ='abc'+chkVals.length;
            obj.somethingElse  ='def'+chkVals.length;
        }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the entire complex object into the chosen items list. The downside is that pre-populating the list of selected values gets a little trickier. A jquery grep comes in handy here.

https://jsfiddle.net/4p3bsgmg/1/

```
    <!-- ko foreach: items -->
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.chosenItems" />
        <span data-bind="text: displayName"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <br/><br/>
    Chosen Items: <span data-bind='text: ko.toJSON(chosenItems)'></span>



<script>
    var viewModel = {
        items: ko.observableArray([
            { id : 1, displayName: "Bob's Burgers", name : "Robert J. Burger Co." },
            { id : 2, displayName: "Late Nite Slice", name : "Pizza Inc." },
            { id : 3, displayName: "Luigie's Pizza Tower", name : "Pizza Inc." }
        ]),
        chosenItems: ko.observableArray(),
        load: function(selectedItems){
            var selectedItems = $.grep(this.items(), function(val){
                return selectedIdsFromAWebmethodCall.indexOf(val.id) >= 0;
            });
            for(var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++){
                this.chosenItems.push(selectedItems[i]);
            }
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    var selectedIdsFromAWebmethodCall = [1];
    viewModel.load(selectedIdsFromAWebmethodCall);
</script>
```

Comment: The issue I have is that I cannot put those extra fields in the list. They need to be generated when the items are selected.